# Change object attributes based on HTML input (angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I don't know how to proceed with my problem, so that's why i'm hopping you guys could help.
I have the HTML form which looks like this:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="Uid" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Uid</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="subscriber.subscriberUid" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="subscriber.name" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="surname" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Surename</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="subscriber.surname">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my angular app, where i store subscriber data, so i can insert it:

```
//subscriber
$scope.subscriber = {
     "subscriberUid" : ""
     "name": "",
     "surname": "",
};
```

So where is the tricky part for me.
If user inputs the subscriberUid then my subscriber object shoul look like this:

```
 //subscriber
    $scope.subscriber = {
         "subscriberUid" : ""
         "name": "",
         "surname": "",
    };
```

Otherwise it needs to look like this and back-end will auto generate it:

```
 //subscriber
    $scope.subscriber = {
         "name": "",
         "surname": "",
    };
```

How to achieve desired effect?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can't you leave `subscriberUid` blank and just let the back-end do the rest?

Comment: Hi!

The problem is if i leave "subscriberUid" : "" (blank), then backend threats as subscriberUid is "inserted" and i can't be blank.
So  i assume that if subscriberUid is not inserted in HTML then this line also needs to be removed in subscriber object.

Comment: Can't the back-end check if `subscriberUid` is blank and do something about it? The way I see it there isn't any point in making object properties go missing when you could just pass whatever was submitted to the backend and let it decide what to do.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a option. If this would be in my hand than i would do it, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check before sending to backend if $subscriber.subscriberUid is empty and just remove it from object with

```
        if($scope.subscriber.subscriberUid == ""){
            delete $scope.subscriber.subscriberUid;
        }
```